# How to use parent's mixin as a child model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Im trying to use a parent's mixin as a child model, but I couldn't make it work as the mixin isn't resolved on the 'data' definition.

Here is a fiddle:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
    <div>
      USER: {{user}}
      <br/>
      EMAIL: {{email}}      
    </div>
    <input-list :field="field" v-for="field in fields"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
Vue.component('input-list', {
    name: 'InputList',
  props: ['field'],
  template: '<div>{{field.id}}: <input type="text" v-model="field.model"/></div>'
})

var userData = {
    data() {
    return {
      user: 'foo',
      email: 'foo@barbar'
    }
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  mixins: [userData],
  data() {
    return {
        fields: [
          {
            id: "UserName",
            model: this.user
          },
          {
            id: "Email",
            model: this.email
          }
        ]
      }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rafalages/rp7bu2qt/9/

The expected result would be update parent mixin value in the child input.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with the mixin, but rather the overall design, if you we to use data instead of mixin, you'd see the same behaviour.

This will not work they way you intend it to.

Two things about *Vue* worth re-iterating:

- You pass props down and emit events up
- Mutating a prop will not update the parent

more reading here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

There is a note at the bottom

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.

But my recommendation is to think of this as a side-effect rather than a feature. You should not rely on the child from updating the value. The only reliable way (outside of other state management) is to pass a function.

Another issue is that referencing `this` in data during creation will not work

```
  data: {
    fields: [
      {
        id: "UserName",
        model: this.user
      },
      {
        id: "Email",
        model: this.email
      }
    ]
  }
```

This will not use the data from `this.user` and will be set to null. You can use the `mounted` life-cycle function to set these like this:

```
mounted() {
  this.fields = [
    {
      id: "UserName",
      model: this.user
    },
    {
      id: "Email",
      model: this.email
    },
  ]
}
```

which will set it to use the initial values. But referencing an object like this inside another object will also serve to create new bindings, essentially cutting the reactivity. This means that you'll use the values from those objects, but changes to  `this.fields[1].model` will not update `this.email`

here is a semi-working fiddle that attempts to use your current design

https://jsfiddle.net/rp7bu2qt/113/

notice that...

- the binding is using v-model, which is shorthand for binding a prop and an emit/update to a value
- you see an error

> You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.

- changes to the input fields do not change the original data, just the content of `fields[n].model`